# GLM for count data

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, count-data

I ran an experiment with an eye tracker and my data frame has this look:

```
               Condition   DWellsAOI1 DwellsAOI2  TotalDwells 
Participant1       1             12         13            25
Participant2       2            100         11           111
Participant3       1             50         50           100
```

and so on. `DWellsAOI1` counts the number of dwells on AOI1. Each participant belongs to one condition only, and the duration of the experiment is not fixed, so different `TotalDwells`.

I was trying to check if there is a significant difference among the between conditions in terms of `DwellsAOI1`, and my first approach was to compute the percentages (`DwellsAOI1/TotalDwells`) and run anova. However, data violates both the assumptions.

I searched on Google and I found that I can use a generalized linear model (GLM) with binomial family.

Currently I'm running it like this:

```
mod <- glm(cbind(DwellsAOI1,TotalDwells-DwellsAOI1) ~ Condition,
               data=df, family=binomial("logit"))
summary(aov(mod))
```

Is it the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to check whether you're treating Condition as a categorical or continuous variable - it'll make a difference if there are more than two levels. Some reading about general linear models would also be a good idea before you start using them in earnest.

Comment: It's a categorical variable...in the real case they are two strings

Comment: Over-dispersion is something to watch out for - is the spread of proportions for different participants unexpectedly large within each condition?

Comment: Well yes, since the durations are different.

Comment: Given the differences in duration, & hence total dwells, is the spread of proportions for different participants unexpectedly large within each condition? Check the model diagnostics - unusually large deviance is a tell-tale sign.

Comment: In my first comment read "generalized" for "general"; in my third the deviance in question is the *residual* deviance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a strong assumption with this model: that the probability of dwelling on AOI1 in each trial depends only on the Condition factor & is not affected by variability between participants or between sessions.<sup>†</sup> So the danger is a misleadingly precise estimate of the effect of Condition. Examine the model diagnostics carefully, & note that the residual deviance should be approximately equal to the residual degrees of freedom; much greater is a tell-tale sign of over-dispersion. If the assumption seems untenable, alternatives include fitting a beta-binomial model, using a quasi-likelihood approach with an estimated dispersion parameter, & fitting a generalized linear mixed model with a random intercept term representing the participant-session effect.

† To see this: the fitted model will be the same as if you'd summed up dwell counts across each condition before the analysis, leaving you with a two-way contingency table.